# Select Token C# Json array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have the code below and I want to select the child note when I am accessing 'a'.
But the string result is returning null when I select the 'character' node

```
JObject jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson);
Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode.Equals(true));
var a = (JArray)jObj["cast"];
string result = (string)a.SelectToken("character");
```

This is the JSON response i get from 'a':

```
{[
{
"character": "Eddard Stark",
"credit_id": "5256c8ad19c2956ff60478a6",
"id": 48,
"name": "Sean Bean",
"profile_path": "/iIxP2IzvcLgr5WaTBD4UfSqaV3q.jpg",
"order": 0
},
{
"character": "Jon Snow",
"credit_id": "5256c8af19c2956ff6047af6",
"id": 239019,
"name": "Kit Harington",
"profile_path": "/dwRmvQUkddCx6Xi7vDrdnQL4SJ0.jpg",
"order": 0
},
{
"character": "Robert Baratheon",
"credit_id": "5256c8ad19c2956ff60478e2",
"id": 13633,
"name": "Mark Addy",
"profile_path": "/tGWYaLPIGvPJiKx9KzTBMITo7uK.jpg",
"order": 1
},
{
"character": "Daenerys Targaryen",
"credit_id": "5256c8af19c2956ff60479f6",
"id": 1223786,
"name": "Emilia Clarke",
"profile_path": "/tB1nE2LJH81f5UMiGhKCSlaqsF1.jpg",
"order": 1
},
{
"character": "Tyrion Lannister",
"credit_id": "5256c8b219c2956ff6047cd8",
"id": 22970,
"name": "Peter Dinklage",
"profile_path": "/xuB7b4GbARu4HN6gq5zMqjGbkwF.jpg",
"order": 2
}
]}
```

Comment: where is cast in your json?

Comment: how about specifying an index for your array? `string result = (string)a[0].SelectToken("character");`

Comment: @MichaelFaisst thanks that worked fine. I can get the first character element. I suppose i can loop through them all to get the one i need

Comment: @Mayamiko yes that would be correct : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create model class You can use http://json2csharp.com/, and deserialize it using Json.NET

use the following namespace

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

model class and DeserializeObject method

```
        public class RootObject
    {
        public string character { get; set; }
        public string credit_id { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string profile_path { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
    }


var x =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(myjsondata);
var character = x[index].character;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON seems to be incorrect, you have to remove begin and end curly braces.

Correct JSON:

```
[{
    "character": "Eddard Stark",
    "credit_id": "5256c8ad19c2956ff60478a6",
    "id": 48,
    "name": "Sean Bean",
    "profile_path": "/iIxP2IzvcLgr5WaTBD4UfSqaV3q.jpg",
    "order": 0
}, {
    "character": "Jon Snow",
    "credit_id": "5256c8af19c2956ff6047af6",
    "id": 239019,
    "name": "Kit Harington",
    "profile_path": "/dwRmvQUkddCx6Xi7vDrdnQL4SJ0.jpg",
    "order": 0
}, {
    "character": "Robert Baratheon",
    "credit_id": "5256c8ad19c2956ff60478e2",
    "id": 13633,
    "name": "Mark Addy",
    "profile_path": "/tGWYaLPIGvPJiKx9KzTBMITo7uK.jpg",
    "order": 1
}, {
    "character": "Daenerys Targaryen",
    "credit_id": "5256c8af19c2956ff60479f6",
    "id": 1223786,
    "name": "Emilia Clarke",
    "profile_path": "/tB1nE2LJH81f5UMiGhKCSlaqsF1.jpg",
    "order": 1
}, {
    "character": "Tyrion Lannister",
    "credit_id": "5256c8b219c2956ff6047cd8",
    "id": 22970,
    "name": "Peter Dinklage",
    "profile_path": "/xuB7b4GbARu4HN6gq5zMqjGbkwF.jpg",
    "order": 2
}]
```

Equivalent Model class:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public string character { get; set; }
    public string credit_id { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string profile_path { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize using the below code:

It will give you `List` or `Array` of `SampleClass` object. You can use `foreach` loop or `LINQ` to get all the `character` field.

```
List<SampleClass> lsObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SampleClass>>(strJson);

    foreach(SampleClass obj in lsObj)
    {
        string character = obj.character;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you ca just parse your string to `JObject` directly with `JObject.Parse()` method or `JArray.Parse()`. Then you can just iterate through you array and get array objects by index: `jsonObj[0]`. And if you want get some specific value of that object - use `Value<T>()` method^ `jsonObj[0].Value<string>("character")`